# Filter Dates which are NOT in current month using power Query

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

in power bi's **query editor**, i needed a date column to be split into two more columns. One as *"In current month"* and the other one is *"Not in current month"*

for *"In current month"* i used `Date.IsInCurrentMonth`, now i need the same for *"Not in Current Month"*

any help is appreciated.
Ty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `not`.

```
if not Date.IsInCurrentMonth([Date])
then "Not in Current Month"
else "In Current Month"
```

Or the other way around

```
if Date.IsInCurrentMonth([Date])
then "In Current Month"
else "Not in Current Month"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this formula that worked for me:

```
if (Date.Month([Order Date]) = Date.Month(DateTime.Date(DateTime.LocalNow())))
then "Current Month"
else "Not Current Month"
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post, I did something slightly different because I didn't want to you the IF statement.

```
Logical.ToText(Date.IsInCurrentMonth([PROCESSDATE])) = "false"
```